# FsUnit.Xunit list should contain an x such that f x

Tags: f#, xunit, fsunit

I am not sure how to write my test in `FsUnit.Xunit`.

I want to check that at least one element in my list satisfies a predicate. I know how to write this using `should be True`, but usually you can get better error messages by using the specialized functions.

Hopefully this code makes it clear what I am trying to achieve:

```ml
open Xunit
open FsUnit.Xunit

type Foo = 
  {
    X : int
  }

[<Fact>]
let ``squares`` () =
  let xs =
    [ { X = 1 }; { X = 2 }; { X = 3 } ]
    |> List.map (fun foo -> { X = foo.X * foo.X })

  actual 
  |> should exists (satisfies (fun foo -> foo.X = 9)) // Not real code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this:

```
xs
    |> Seq.map (fun foo -> foo.X)
    |> should contain 9
```

Error output is useful:

```
Expected: Contains 8
Actual:   seq [1; 4; 9]
```

If you want more context, you can do this instead:

```
open FsUnit.CustomMatchers

...

xs |> should containf (fun foo -> foo.X = 9)
```

Error output is:

```
Expected: Contains <fun:squares@21-1>
Actual:   [{ X = 1 }; { X = 4 }; { X = 9 }]
```

The only downside of this approach is that the "Expected" message no longer displays the specific value you're looking for.

Comment: Not a bad solution, although the error message now loses the extra context (imagine `Foo` contained more members)

Comment: I think I found what you want: `FsUnit.CustomMatchers.containf`. Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think `containf` is the best we're going to do!

Comment: I want to use _containf_ but I don't have FSUnit.CustomMatchers.  
I'm using FsUnit 4.0.6 and NUnit 3.13.2 .

Comment: I think `CustomMatchers` is for xUnit, not for NUnit.